# Is there any situation in which it would be appropriate to use unless... else?

Tags: coding-style, ruby, code-formatting

This construction is [considered wrong](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)

```
unless
  #..
else
  #..
end
```

This is for the general reason of double-negative confusions.  It translates to:

```
if not 
  #..
if not not
  #..
end
```

*We all agree this is confusing.*

---

Is there any situation (include semantic) that the `unless..else` construction would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 12):

I've not worked with ruby, but Perl has a similar construct which has the same kind of baggage around it.

There is no structural difference between these 3 constructs:

```
if condition
    OneThing()
else
    AnotherThing()

unless condition
    AnotherThing()
else:
    OneThing()

if not condition
    AnotherThing()
else:
    OneThing()
```

However, semantically, I think the reason that people recommend it is that `unless condition` is really just syntactic sugar for `if not condition`. The difference is that not every language has `unless` so the latter is more instantly readable to a new programmer. When introducing `unless` it is usually in the context of the above definition.

Using `unless then else` just confuses things further, because while `unless` is a helpful shortcut, `unless else` adds confusion by having an unfamiliar construct used in an unneccessary way.

Any `unless then else` can trivially be rewritten as `if then else`, so I would suggest that there is no case where `unless then else` improves the readability or computability of the code.

Comment: Right. You can always switch the branches around once you have two of them. `unless` … `else` is confusing in English as well, using it in a program isn't better. (I haven't seen or heard it used in either speech or writing, there's probably a reason for that!)

Comment: Unless you go out of your way, its uncommon to use "Unless" in English. I do like it in programming as can help clarify singleton branches, especially with lots of possibilities; eg. `unless 1 of 100 options: do a thing`. But unless used properly, it can confuse readability, otherwise it is fine!

Comment: Interesting usage there :-) Would it be better if it was `unless` … `otherwise` instead of `unless` … `else`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yeah, that was kind of on purpose. But I doubt changing `unless else` to `unless otherwise` would improve readability at all. I think just write `if not then else` and be done with it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag interesting suggestion, with `otherwise`.  I have found the case arise where my `if not` condition is conceptually more important than my `if` condition, but writing `if not` as the first statement reads worse than `unless`.

Comment: I do use `unless .. otherwise` in some edge-cases of common speech. Maybe more as a warning: "*Unless* you [blah] such thing will happen, *otherwise* it will turn out OK"

Answer (score 4):

#### No.

Any construct of that type can be rewritten in your second form, with better clarity.

In most languages, the `if` `not` `not` collapses into a simple `if` anyway, so the mind-bending consequences of `unless` `else` become especially pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want "unless" because it easily leads to confusion because an if condition with a built in negative would be just bad design. Also because it's easy to just use an "if".

You would get constructs like:

```
unless !(x=3) {

unless(item.isnotred){
```

which you have to read twice, where an easy:

```
if (x=3)

if (item.isred){
```

is very clear.

Unless operator leads to double negatives which should be avoided.